# Unify the direction of a normal curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, normals

I want to have the same direction of the normals. I can not do it manually because I have 900 segments and it impossible for me to selected one by one the segments that have the same direction before reversing! there is a way to do this quickly?
[image]

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_sz6H3NtE_dmloWXVQQzRRX00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could prob do with a script, that runs thru the splines, looks at the direction of s[1].co - s[0].co selects if "wrong way" and run reverse direction op on selected, in which case a small test file would be handy.

Comment: Right, I tried to do with python, but I have enough experience in programming.
file attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that changes direction based on the difference  of angle between first and last spline points and the x_axis.  Run in edit mode.  You may need to change based on which direction to "unify" to.  As is it unifies all curves in the test file you posted to run right to left.  Change either the angle test or the x_axis direction to make all go left to right for instance.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from mathutils import Vector
from math import degrees, radians
curve_object = context.edit_object
x_axis = Vector((1, 0, 0))
# deselect all 
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for s in curve_object.data.splines:
    v = (s.points[1].co - s.points[-1].co).xyz

    angle = v.angle(x_axis)
    print(degrees(angle))
    if angle > radians(90):
        for p in s.points:
            p.select = True


bpy.ops.curve.switch_direction()
```

Comment: perfect, it is strange that this is not natively in Blender. Thank you